# Setting up different behavior on intranet vs internet on one page

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have two versions of a JavaScript library: A public version and a private version, where only internal users have access to the private version, and the functionality in the private version is a superset of the public version, and includes an editing mode that I'd rather not expose in the public version. So private users should be able to edit the document and submit it other private users for review/re-posting, whereas public users shouldn't have access.

If I add them both to my html pages like

```
<script src='[public_version]'></script>
<script src='[private_version]'></script>
```

The private version should overwrite everything in the public version, or? Is this an bad way to create one page with different functionality depending on public or private usage?

--- Edit ---

Let me clarify: For my purposes, this has to be a single page, not two. So my question is: Is there a better way to achieve this behavior with a restriction that it can only be 1 shared page?

--- Edit 2 ---

The first paragraph has been updated to state that it is editing features added in the private edition that I don't want to expose in the public edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to detect in server, that some users are from internet but other users are from intranet, then you should be also able to include into HTML the first library in first case, and other library second case (e.g by return different html file). If your server cannot detect that difference then this is security vulnerability.

The access to edit document should be checked on server side and not depend of frontend libraries.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad habit. You better make one page for public use and one page for private use (which is protected). Then you can make a shared Javascript library and extend it when needed for the private page.

Comment: I agree with ruttydm

Comment: I have updated my question. My constraint is that it has to be only 1 page

Comment: @ControlAltDel I think we need more context. Is this a static page? Are you using a backend? Why does it need to be one page?

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that the public users might be able to use the private functions by manipulating the script(if this bid a big problem it would mean something else is wrong bin your applications design though).
If the library isn't to big this is an ok way of doing it but a cleaner way would be to separately load the different functionalitys rather then overriding them(imo)
Edit by ok I mean it would work not that bit is advisable

Comment: But the public users wouldn't have the extra & modified functions from the private version, because the private version won't load. Are you saying there's another way for public users to access the private functionality?

Comment: I was operating under the assumption that both are loaded but the overriding takes place only if the user is on the intranet.

Comment: I read your recent edits and one of the other answers already said this but it's important THE CLIENT SHOULD NOT BE ABLE TO CONTROL WHO IS ALLOWED TO EDIT DOCUMENTS. If the only thing stopping private users from editing documents is that they they don't have the JavaScript library you need to rethink how your application works(perhaps a login could be added for intranet users)

Answer (score 0):

you can use requirejs(RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader) library in order to dynamicaly load script to your browser depend on your condition.